# how to remove the duplicates within an array of arrays based on the array key in php?

Tags: php

I have this multi dimensional array. At first glance it's duplicated because the id is the same for all three. but if you check the "notes" key, it's not. but I want to remove the duplicates from this array based form the "id" . how to do that? because array_unique does not work

```
[
    {
        "id": 69,
        "text": "hello text",
        "desc": "hello desc",
        "state": false,
        "type": false,
        "notes": "Created",
        "type_id": 25185,
        "state_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 69,
        "text": "hello text",
        "desc": "hello desc",
        "state": false,
        "type": false,
        "notes": "Accepted",
        "type_id": 25185,
        "state_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 69,
        "text": "hello text",
        "desc": "hello desc",
        "state": false,
        "type": false,
        "notes": "In Progress",
        "type_id": 25185,
        "state_id": 0
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or shorter:

```
$result = array_values(array_column($yourArray, null, 'id')))
```

$result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 69
            [text] => hello text
            [desc] => hello desc
            [state] => 
            [type] => 
            [notes] => In Progress
            [type_id] => 25185
            [state_id] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all but the last object with a matching id:

https://paiza.io/projects/mZ-e3zzmyFWq6XY-qjKLjg

```
<?php

$arr = [
    (object)array(
        "id" => 69,
        "text" => "hello text",
        "desc" => "hello desc",
        "state" => false,
        "type" => false,
        "notes" => "Created",
        "type_id" => 25185,
        "state_id"=> 0
    ),
    (object)array(
        "id" => 69,
        "text" => "hello text",
        "desc" => "hello desc",
        "state" => false,
        "type" => false,
        "notes" => "Accepted",
        "type_id" => 25185,
        "state_id" => 0
    ),
    (object)array(
        "id" => 69,
        "text" => "hello text",
        "desc" => "hello desc",
        "state" => false,
        "type" => false,
        "notes" => "In Progress",
        "type_id" => 25185,
        "state_id" => 0
    )
];

foreach($arr as $key1 => $obj1){
    foreach($arr as $key2 => $obj2){
        if($obj1->id === $obj2->id && $key1 !== $key2){
            unset($arr[$key1]);
        }
    
    }
}

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 69
            [text] => hello text
            [desc] => hello desc
            [state] => 
            [type] => 
            [notes] => In Progress
            [type_id] => 25185
            [state_id] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: undefined offset 0

Comment: @sasori not sure what you're doing. If you check out the link, it works with the data you provided.

Comment: @sasori hit the check to accept if you liked my answer